# How many 6-digit numbers can be formed using {1, 2, . . . , 9} with no repetitions such that 1 and 2 do not occur in consecutive positions?

Tags: combinatorics

I tried to solve it as $2\cdot8\cdot6!$ 
but I don't think its correct 
how can satisfy the condition

1 and 2 do not occur in consecutive positions?

Comment: This is not clear.  Do you mean to exclude strings containing $11$ or $22$ or do you mean to exclude strings containing $12$?

Comment: he wants us to find a way to form 6 digit numbers by the number 1-9 without repeating numbers and 1 and 2 shouldn't be together

Comment: exclude containing 12

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Include some examples of good strings and bad strings.  Take out the "Blockquotes".

Comment: What about $21$? Is that excluded too?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just calculate the number of numbers that have either $12$ or $21$ in them, and subtract from the total number of six-digit numbers.

There are five two-digit slots where the $12$ or $21$ can go, and $_7P_4 = 840$ ways to populate the remaining four places with something besides $1$ and $2$. So, $2 \cdot 5 \cdot 840 = 8400$ such numbers.

Subtract these from the $_9P_6$ total ways and you're done.

Comment: The way I read the question, neither $12$ nor $21$ is permitted.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Correct! That's why I subtract them out.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Oh, I think I see why you commented.

Answer (score 0):

Well have you ever heard of the stars and bars problem.

So first take two cases:

**Case 1**:- When both 1 & 2 are not included.
$7\choose{6}$$\cdot6!$

**Case 2**:- When both 1 & 2 are included

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

**Case 3**:- When either 1 or 2 is included
$8\choose6$$\cdot6!$

Comment: You overlooked the case that exactly one of $1$ or $2$ appears in the number.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's just $1,2$ that is not allowed in consecutive positions in that order, I get:

$$^9P_6 - 5(^7P_4) = 56280$$

This is the number of permutations of $6$ from $9$, minus the number of positions of $1,2$ which is $5$, times the permutations of $4$ from $7$, which is the number of ways the other 4 locations can be filled by the other $7$ numbers.

Comment: The way I read the question, neither $12$ nor $21$ is permitted.

Comment: Sure, it wasn't totally clear, but for your reading, it would be -10 instead of -5 in the equation.